# angularJS ng-dropdown-multiselect implementing scrolling event for infinite scrolling

Tags: java, html, css, angularjs

I have created a multi select dropdown using AngularJS and bootstrap and added search and scrollable options and it's working fine.
I need to implement infinite scrolling when scrolling in the multi select dropdown scrollable bar.It's not working for multi select dropdown but infinite scrolling works for the div.
I see events for onItemSelect and onItemDeselect don't find any event for scrolling for multi select dropdown.

I include the following code:

```
<div  ng-dropdown-multiselect=""  options="user" selected-model="userModel" extra-settings="example14settings" when-scrolled="loadMore()"></div>

$scope.example14settings = {
    scrollableHeight: '100px',
    scrollable: true,
    enableSearch: true
};

$http.get('user').success(function(response){
//users list has huge data need to implemented infinite scroll
          $scope.userList = response;
          $scope.users = $scope.userList.slice(0,10);
});
 $scope.loadMore = function (){
       $scope.user = $scope.users.slice(0, $scope.user.length + 8);
 };
```

Below is working infinite scrolling code for external div not inside mutlselect dropdown also after search it's not doing infinite scroll for next dataset.

Code:

```
<div   id="fixed" ng-dropdown-multiselect=""  options="user"
       selected-model="userModel"
       extra-settings="example14settings" when-scrolled="loadMore()"></div>

#fixed {
 height: 400px;
 overflow : auto;
}
$scope.example14settings = {
    enableSearch: true
};

angular.module('App').directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

How to I add infinite scrolling inside scrolling for angular multiselect dropdown?
Also when user search for something the infinite scrolling should work on searched data when scrolling down?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted here, what I can see is that you're not applying your "loadMore()" function (but that may not be your only problem).  Try this:

```
angular.module('App').directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply('loadMore()');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Try using your "ng-dropdown-multiselect" like this:

```
<ng-dropdown-multiselect when-scrolled="loadMore()"></ng-dropdown-multiselect>"
```

You need to bind to the element not the attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I am adding when-scrolled="loadMore()" in html and it's calling loadMore() when scrolling down.infinite scrolling working  in a div, I need to apply it to ng-dropdown-multiselect scrollable bar.

Comment: Your issue is that you are calling the directive on the "div" and not on the "select".  Your select is an attribute rather than an element.

Comment: Do you know how to call it on sleect? I am using ng-dropdown-multiselect with below setting? is there any event for scroll like onselect event?              $scope.example14settings = {
    scrollableHeight: '100px',
    scrollable: true,
    enableSearch: true
};

Comment: Did you try using the ng-dropdown-multiselect as an element rather than an attribute as I suggested above?  I looked at the code for ng-dropdown-multiselect and it says that it can be an attribute or an element.